# can “today” be used for present, past and future?

Tags: grammar

"I usually go by car, but today I went by bus." - is it correct? Can we use Past Simple with "today"?

Comment: Is it still today for you? If so, yes.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can and your sentence is correct.

It can also be used with future:

> Yesterday, I went by bus, but today I will walk

Answer (score 0):

Consider that the word **today** encompasses an entire 24-hour period*. As such, you could include this word in any sentence referring to an event in the past, present, or future relative to your current time within the day.

---

*or perhaps the period of daylight, since you might otherwise say *tonight*